# Using Meteor Methods but still getting error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I'm using [Meteor methods](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/security-with-methods) to avoid updating the database on the client-side but still getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID. [403]

I didn't notice it affecting the application until configuring Facebook and Twitter login for the accounts-ui package. Again, the only database operations I'm performing on the client-side are finds.

```
    if(Meteor.isClient) {
      $scope.deleteTask = function(task) {
        $meteor.call("deleteTask", task._id);
      };
    }
    
    if(Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.methods({
        deleteTask: function (taskId) {
          var task = Tasks.findOne(taskId);
          if (task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
            alert("Only a tasks owner may delete the task.")
            throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
          }
          else {
            Tasks.remove(taskId);
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

EDIT: I should mention that the application still works fine on localhost even though that error appears, but does not work (and still shows that error) when I deploy it to one of meteor's test servers.

Comment: can you post your method call and the method itself, please?

Comment: I've added some code above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that it was coming from my accounts-ui configurations in a totally different file!

Answer (score 2):

You are running the code on the client. You have two choices to immediately solve the problem:

1. Place the method definition in a file under the `/server` directory in your app.
2. Wrap the method definition inside of an `if (Meteor.isServer) {}` block.

The actual error is happening because the method is running on the client (see above) and updating a collection with a non-id-based selector. For example:

```
Posts.update({awesome: false}, {...});
```

Whereas on the client you can only make updates like:

```
Posts.update(postId, {...});
```

If you prefer to keep [latency compensation](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-latency-compensation) and write a client stub you can, but you'll need to modify your update as seen in the second example above.

Suggested reading: [Structuring your application](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Comment: I've already got wrapped all database operations in "if (Meteor.isServer) {}" and still get the error.

Comment: Try my first suggestion and put it in a file under the `/server` directory. There may be some other unrelated issue going on in your file which just isn't evaluating this correctly. Also make sure there isn't a second definition remaining on the client after doing this. If you still get an error, but the error text has changed, please indicate that.

Comment: I've moved all server code to a file under a `/server` directory and still get the same error. The operations still work on localhost, even though that error appears, but the application does not work when I deploy it to one of meteor's test servers.

Comment: You need to search your code for `deleteTask`. The only way you'd still be getting that code on the client in a web console on localhost is if you have a second definition of the method that is still exposed to the client. If you have a repo I can examine, I'd be happy to have a quick look.

Comment: Found that it was coming from my accounts-ui configurations in a totally different file!